# Apache Thrift oneway методы

Tags: rpc, apache-thrift

Расскажите, пожалуйста, чем отличаются описания двух методов

```
service MyService {
  void test1();
  oneway void test2();
}
```

> The `oneway` modifier indicates that the client only makes a request and does not wait for any response at all. Oneway methods MUST be void.

Но любой `void` метод говорит, что клиент не ждет никаких результатов. Тогда зачем `oneway`?

Или разница в том, что обычный метод выполняется синхронно и клиенту возвращается управление только после отработки метода на сервере, а `oneway` дернули и забыли? И как следствие, из `oneway` не может прийти исключение